# Uneven spacing around ellipsis in $[A_1;\dotsc;A_n]$

Tags: spacing, amsmath, punctuation

I've noticed that when a `\dotsc` has a semicolon on each side, there's uneven space around the ellipsis created. With

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&[A_1;\dotsc;A_n]\\
&[A_1;\dots;A_n]\\
&[A_1;\ldots;A_n]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

As you can see, both `\dots` and `\ldots` work fine.

Is this a known problem? I'm using `amsmath` 2013/01/14 v2.14.

Comment: I just noticed you did nevermind.  I always use `\ldots` though.

Comment: I didn't know the command `\dotsc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the behavior is inherited from ams-tex -- but there's a particular "understanding" in ams-tex that hasn't been inherited.

ams-tex assumes that `\ldots` will be used only in text, and then (quoting from internal documentation that is not distributed publicly)

> In text, we want to ignore spaces before \dots, and we want to leave
>   an extra thin space if the next token, which we get with a \futurelet,
>   is a , or . or ; or : or ? or !  Otherwise (another letter or symbol
>   comes next) we want to leave an ordinary space.

this can easily be demonstrated by processing this file with (plain) tex:

```
\input amstex
$$ A_1 ; \dots ; A_n \qquad A_1 ; \dotsc ; A_n \qquad A_1 ; \ldots ; A_n $$
\bye
```

the result inserts the thin space after `\ldots` as well as after `\dotsc`.
`\dots` alone has the uniform spacing desired in this context.

alas, there's no documentation in `amsmath.dtx` regarding why this change was made.

a look into *joy of tex*, p.152, gives another hint: `\dotsc` is used in an example where the dots terminate a (mathematical) phrase:

```
Consider the infinite sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3,\dots$.
```

although in thi example the next thing is a period (end of sentence), it could as well be a semicolon (end of clause), in which case the extra thin space is desirable, and the recommendation ("the proper thing") "is to tell AMS-TeX which sort of dots it should be using:"

```
Consider the infinite sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3,\dotsc$.
```

for myself, i would use `\dots` rather than either `\ldots` or `\dotsc`, examining the output only to check whether i really should have used `\cdots`.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a "known problem" It is a pretty explicit design aim. The code for `\dotsc` has

```
\ifx\@let@token;\@ldots\,
```

that is it tests for a following `;` and adds a thin space `\,`

Sadly I suspect the reasons for that choice are somewhat lost in time (unless Barbara appears with a rationale)

Comment: My guess is Barbara's response will be similar to [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) (p 13, section **4.3 Dots**) which suggests: `\dotsc` for "dots with commas". And, `;` is not a comma `,`.

Comment: @Werner, reading the documentation: a low blow:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- it would be a real shame to think that *writing* documentation was wasted time ... (of course, there *are* some people who are simply compulsive readers.)